# Where [how ?] is the path for lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php defined?

Tags: cakephp, ubuntu-14.04, cakephp-2.5

Downloading the proj. from online server & trying to run it in my localhost, but I am getting the path problems. I do not see where the path is defined, yet, I am getting the error :

```
[Mon Aug 22 14:12:10.681539 2016] [:error] [pid 1186] [client 127.0.0.1:47932] PHP Warning:  include(/home3/username/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/proj/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 547
```

The online server had its path in `/home3/username`, but I have `/var/www` in my localhost.

I do not see where `home3`, or `username` is mentioned in my local ( doing ctrl+shift+f ).

I am using Cakephp v2.5.3

**------ Update -----**

Besides the path, I see Cakephp 2 will not work with php7, so installing php5 managed to get the project working.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/756879/cant-install-php5-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Try to remove cache or set debug > 0 in core.php

Comment: @Bart I've set it to 2, but still nothing.

Comment: @Bart & I removed cache.

Comment: So check the CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH constant in your app/webroot/index.php

Comment: Thanks @Bart. Its up & working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to app/webroot and open index.php file, find  define function CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH, and change value to your path.

```
/**
 * The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 * Un-comment this line to specify a fixed path to CakePHP.
 * This should point at the directory containing `Cake`.
 *
 * For ease of development CakePHP uses PHP's include_path. If you
 * cannot modify your include_path set this value.
 *
 * Leaving this constant undefined will result in it being defined in Cake/bootstrap.php
 *
 * The following line differs from its sibling
 * /app/webroot/index.php
 */
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'C:' . DS . 'xampp' . DS . 'htdocs' . DS . 'cakephp' . DS . 'lib');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the project from the online server and running it on your localhost then, please Clear the files in app/tmp/ . After that it will be working fine.